# Equation for Tangent Plane and Linear Approximation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need help finding an equation for a tangent plane to the following graph at the point $(1,2,5)$:
$$z=f(x,y)=x^2+2xy$$
For this question, I got $z=6x+2y-5$ as the tangent plane. Can someone verify this?

Also, I need help with linear approximation. I want to approximate $f(1.1,1.9)$. So for this I think that I should start with $f(1,2)$. However what do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is that $f(1,1.9) \approx. f(1,2)+ f_x(1, 2)(x-x_0)+ f_y (1,2)(y-y_0)=5+ 6(1-1.1)+ 2(2-1.9) = 5-0.6+  0.2= 4.6$. i.e., you consider the change of the function along the tangent plane. The actual value at $(1.1, 1.9)$ is $5.39$, so the approximation is not that good.

Comment: I am editing, please give me some time before downvoting.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Please see latest edit.